# How can I fill two-dimensional arrayList with one dimensional?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem that, whenever I try to fill two dimensional arrayList  (5x5) with one dimensional, I get index out of bounds exceptions. I guess that's because the square Array doesn't have index 0 value yet, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
ArrayList<Character> c = new ArrayList<>();
        
// Copy character by character into arraylist 
for (int i = 0; i < finalArray.length(); i++) { 
    c.add(i, finalArray.charAt(i));
} 

ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> square = new ArrayList<>();
//square.add(new ArrayList<>()); 

int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        square.get(j).add(i, c.get(k));
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well using get() was the only way to access first row of elements that i found online. As i said i know that it can't get it, that's why i decided to ask this question :)  For someone to help me find a solution to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a “row” List to the outer List before the inner loop. You are also using the wrong index for `square`.

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    square.add(new ArrayList<>()); // Initialize the row
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        square.get(i).add(c.get(k++)); // get(i) not get(j)!
    }
}
```

Note the other simplifications too.

It would be clearer to do this:

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    List<Character> row = new ArrayList<>();
    square.add(row);
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        row.add(c.get(k++));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works perfectly now. Btw i should've put 5 instead of 4 in for loop, because it's 5x5 array.

Comment: @Radiooactiven - I had no idea that by "2D array" you meant an "ArrayList of ArrayLists". If I wanted a 5x5 array ... I'd probably just declare a 5x5 array ;)  Neverthless, in C# both arrays and lists are 0-based. Meaning "4" is "correct".